# How can I create tree in C that has different types of values in nodes?

Tags: c, tree, nodes

I have to make a tree that has one types of values in all nodes except leaves and I'm not sure how to do that or is it even possible. E.g. int in all nodes but char in leaves. I'm new at programming so I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: google the `union` keyword. Then google tagged unions.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Why do you want to do that? A `char` is an smaller `int` than `int` so having them all be `int` is ok. If you insist, use `union {int i; char c;} data;`. If you meant a *string* then it's probably more logical to do this, but still is not something that you really have to do. Because you know which nodes will be of which types it doesn't seem like you **really** need a `union` or any *generic* data type at all.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I just gave an example, it's more complicated than int and char, I'm creating index tree for index-sequential data organisation and I have two structures, one for leaves and one for the rest because leaves contains pointers to another list of structure...

Comment: Please take a look at [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) (Particularly at **Union-like classes** section with an excellent example) and this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (Also with an example)

Comment: In that case use the `void *` pointer and cast to the right type. But I still suspect that you are using the wrong technique (*probably borrowed from another programming language*). Generic types is not what c is for, although you can do it but you need to have a lot of experience doing it too.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Well the point is to create a tree with indexes of blocks of data in file, so if there are other and easier techniques I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 3):

As in your case it is known what the nodes store (ints in nodes and chars in leaves), it is sufficient to check if a node is a leaf, i.e. if left and right are null. Then use a union for value:

```
struct MYTREE {
    struct MYTREE *left, *right;
    union {
        char *charval;
        int intval;
    } value;
};
```

Comment: Creating a "variant" in C is almost always the incorrect solution. One should avoid using the same memory for unrelated purposes.

Comment: @Lundin, Huh?? That's what unions are for.  Note that here the information of what is stored (which member is in use) is outside the data structure, otherwise a discriminator (outside the union) would be needed to know what member of the union is in use.

Comment: No, the only reasonable use of unions is type punning. That is, accessing the very same binary data through various different types, rather than storing several kinds of unrelated binary data in the same place. Reference for example MISRA-C:2012 rule 19.2.

Comment: @Lundin, the aspect of "unrelatedness" is not yours to comment on. Look at yacc's `yystype`.

Comment: @Lundin, your reference talks of "should" and gives no rationale. I do not see MISRA as a recognized standards setting party.

Comment: You can't type pun an `int` and a `char*` since they are incompatible types that are very unlikely to have the same representation. And in this case it is obvious that they are unrelated, since that is what the OP asked for. I have given a rationale in my answer, I can add further info there.

Answer (score 0):

I partially agree with Lundin and Paul. I would keep the data as void*, and check a node to see if it's a leaf by checking the right & left to be NULL or not. Here is something simple to begin with:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    node* right;
    node* left;
    void* data;
};

int isLeaf(node* n)
{
    return n->right == NULL && n->left == NULL;
}

/* you can also make the two functions below a macro, but that's off-topic */
void addInt(node* n, int i)
{
    n->data = malloc(sizeof(int));
    memcpy(n->data, &i, sizeof(int));
}

void addChar(node* n, char i)
{
    n->data = malloc(sizeof(char));
    memcpy(n->data, &i, sizeof(char));
}

node* node_new()
{
    node* root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->right = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    node* root = node_new();
    addInt(root, 3);

    /* assume you have some node* n1 */
    if (n1->isLeaf())
      addChar(n1, 't');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The canonical way to store a generic type would be this:

```
typedef enum
{
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_STR,
} type_info_t;

typedef struct node_t
{
  struct node_t* left;
  struct node_t* right;
  void*          data;  
  type_info_t    type;
} node_t;


...

int some_value = 1;
node_t node1 = {NULL, NULL, &some_value, TYPE_INT};
node_t node2 = {NULL, NULL, "hello",     TYPE_STR};
```

---

You should avoid creating "variants" by using unions, doing so is bad practice:

- Variants don't scale well at all during maintenance. If you need to add a larger type than those present, the data will grow accordingly. A variant can never be smaller than its largest member + padding bytes.
- They are inefficient, allocating more memory than needed, including padding for the worst case.
- The different types in a variant do not necessarily have the same alignment requirements, if they are of different sizes. The alignment within in variant is unspecified. Similarly, endianess could be an issue.
- Code using variants can be hard to read and understand. One can make mistakes such as first writing a small type, then reading a larger type, with the result that the larger type partially contains indeterminate data.
- You can only initialize one member in the variant explicitly. This means that if the variant was initialized by setting member x, and is then used by accessing member y, then member y could contain an indeterminate value.

(The above covers most of the rationale from MISRA-C:2012 rule 19.2)

Comment: Lundin, most of your arguments I find a bit far sought or untrue. They scale exactly according to types used (if they all are pointers, they are all the same size, but the compiler provides type checks now), so no inefficiency at all; "you can only initialize 1 member", yes indeed - use structs if you have other requirements. Etc. for all your arguments.

Comment: In the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect of C, or any dialect which applies the Common Initial Sequence to all instances of structures that are members in a common union *type*, there is no need for variants to waste space.  In gcc's default dialect, code using variants must be written awkwardly and in a manner which is likely to waste some space, though not as much as would be typically wasted by separately allocating the variant parts as you show above.

Comment: This isn't something I've made up myself, it's common programmer knowledge. If you store 1 `uint8_t` together with a massive struct that takes 1MB of space, then that union will take up 1MB of space no matter if you are actually using the struct member or not. That's the blantantly obvious waste of space, any why it scales poorly. With pointers, you only need to allocate as much memory as you actually use. In addition, a generic struct like the one in my example enables you to also write generic code, which makes the program easier to maintain and probably also faster.

Comment: @supercat That only applies to aggregates that _have_ a common initial sequence, which is more of a special case. The concern here isn't about pointer aliasing and type punning - those are the very reasons unions exist.

Comment: @Lundin: If one has a union of static or automatic duration, it will waste space if it holds things of disparate size, but tree nodes are generally held in allocated storage and, and allocations can sized appropriately.  The CIS is useful on compilers which apply it to objects which appear in a common union *type*, because it allows one to have nodes which start with the same information about linked nodes, node type, node size, etc. followed by information specific to each particular kind of node.

Comment: @supercat In this case the leaves are supposed to have one type and the rest of the nodes another. To call malloc/free each for each node involved in re-balancing of the tree, at every point the tree needs re-balancing, sounds very inefficient. Execution speed is often far more valuable than RAM use.

Comment: As for the common initial sequence, it sounds like you speak about structs and not unions. Unless you mean having a union of several structs with common initial sequence as some sort of attempt to create polymorphism. I think such designs are poor, since you need to know which inherited objects there will be in advance. It is much better to use a  parent class struct, then include that class as the first member of the inherited class. No need for unions and it works very well together with "opaque type" (private encapsulation through incomplete type).

Comment: @Lundin: If the combined size of the common fields is not a multiple of the coarsest alignment among them, segregating the common fields to their own structure will prevent any derived types from using the padding after the common portion.  Further, code which uses derived-type pointers would have to use a different syntax to access the common members than would code which uses parent-type pointers.